# ViewPager save and retrieve selected page

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have a `ViewPager` nested in `RecyclerView` items and I need the `ViewPager` to remember the last page the user selected.

**When I scroll to the last item and then back to the first one, the `ViewPager` positions are "leaked" to other `ViewPager` of the `RecyclerView` items.** 
Please see the GIF below:

[image]

I made a sample project on Github for this issue: 
https://github.com/alaouiali/BnbRecyclerView

Now the code!
First, here is the sample object I'm using to populate the RecyclerView, I use the `position` variable to save the user's last selected page.

```
    public class ParentItem {
          String text;
          int position; //-- Here we save the ViewPager selected page

          public ParentItem(String text) {
              this.text = text;
              this.position = 0;
           }

          public String getText() {
              return text;
          }

          public int getPosition() {
              return position;
          }
          public void setPosition(int pos) {
              this.position = pos;
        }
    }
```

Here is the `RecyclerView.Adapter`:

```
    public VerticalAdapter(Context context, List<ParentItem> myDataset, int appWidth) {
          mDataset = myDataset;
          mContext = context;
          mAppWidth = appWidth;

       }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mDataset.get(position).getPosition());
    holder.mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int positionPager) {
            mDataset.get(position).setPosition(positionPager);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Use setTag(), getTag()  and ViewHolder

Comment: may I know the declaration of your variable positionPager

Comment: @Sheychan There was a mistake in the code. Please see the code again. Thanks